# How to divide an odd number to get x integers?

Tags: c#, math, integer, division

If I want to divide an odd number(for example 7) with 2 to 7, and I want a list of some integers.
if I divine 7 with 4, I should get {1, 2, 2, 2}, or if I divine 5 with 3, I want to get {1, 2, 2}.

How can I do this?

```
        static List<int> OddNumDiv(int oddnum, int divnum)
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();

            result.Add(oddnum / divnum);
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < divnum - 2; i++)
            {
                sum += (int)Math.Round((double)oddnum / divnum, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                result.Add((int)Math.Round((double)oddnum / divnum, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
            }
            result.Add(oddnum - sum);

            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> _7d4 = OddNumDiv(7, 4);
        }
```

This returs with {1, 2, 2, 3} and not what I need {1, 2, 2, 2}

Comment: why do you cast to double?

Comment: So the result is 1x1 and (n-1)/2x2, no need to do division.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli: Because the Math.Round needs double or decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very same idea as in *samidinani* answer (modulo arithmetic), but Linq implementation:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static List<int> OddNumDiv(int oddnum, int divnum) => Enumerable
  .Range(0, divnum)
  .Select(i => oddnum / divnum + (i < divnum - oddnum % divnum ? 0 : 1))
  .ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WhSh19)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add rounded values to the sum. Always calculate the quotient and remainder separately for each division.

Below is the complete code for your desired solution.

```
public static List<int> OddNumDiv(int oddnum, int divnum)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        int quotient = oddnum / divnum; // Find the quotient when oddnum is divided by divnum
        int remainder = oddnum % divnum; // Find the remainder when oddnum is divided by divnum

        // Add quotient to the result list divnum-remainder times
        for (int i = 0; i < divnum - remainder; i++)
        {
            result.Add(quotient);
        }

        // Add quotient+1 to the result list remainder times
        for (int i = 0; i < remainder; i++)
        {
            result.Add(quotient + 1);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Here's the relevant link to learn more about the modulo operator (%): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator

Comment: `Math.DivRem` might be useful here

Comment: @HobeCube I noticed that my answer was initially accepted, but later unaccepted in favor of another answer referencing my idea. I'm curious to know if there was something in my answer that did not work for you or if there was something that you found more helpful in the other answer. Your feedback would be greatly appreciated, as it will help me improve my future answers.